# Entity Framework and DDD - Load required related data before passing entity to business layer

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, persistence, ddd-repositories, ddd-service

Let's say you have a domain object:

```
class ArgumentEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<AnotherEntity> AnotherEntities { get; set; }
}
```

And you have ASP.NET Web API controller to deal with it:

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
public IActionResult DoSomethingWithArgumentEntity(int id)
{
    ArgumentEntity entity = this.Repository.GetById(id);
    this.DomainService.DoDomething(entity);
    ...
}
```

It receives entity identifier, load entity by id and execute some business logic on it with domain service.

**The problem:**
The problem here is with related data. *ArgumentEntity* has *AnotherEntities* collection that will be loaded by EF only if you explicitly ask to do so via Include/Load methods. 
*DomainService* is a part of business layer and should know nothing about persistence, related data and other EF concepts.

*DoDomething* service method expects to receive *ArgumentEntity* instance with loaded *AnotherEntities* collection. 
You would say - it's easy, just Include required data in *Repository.GetById* and load whole object with related collection.

Now lets come back from simplified example to reality of the large application:

1. *ArgumentEntity* is much more complex. It contains multiple related collections and that related entities have their related data too.
2. You have multiple methods of *DomainService*. Each method requires different combinations of related data to be loaded.

I could imagine possible solutions, but all of them are far from ideal:

1. Always load the whole entity -> but it is inefficient and often impossible.
2. Add several repository methods: *GetByIdOnlyHeader, GetByIdWithAnotherEntities, GetByIdFullData* to load specific data subsets in controller -> but controller become aware of which data to load and pass to each service method.
3. Add several repository methods: *GetByIdOnlyHeader, GetByIdWithAnotherEntities, GetByIdFullData* to load specific data subsets in each service method -> it is inefficient, sql query for each service method call. What if you call 10 service methods for one controller action?
4. Each domain method call repository method to load additional required data ( e.g: *EnsureAnotherEntitiesLoaded*) -> it is ugly because my business logic become aware of EF concept of related data.

**The question:**
How would you solve the problem of loading required related data for the entity before passing it to business layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example I can see method `DoSomethingWithArgumentEntity` which obviously belongs to Application Layer. This method has call to `Repository` which belongs to Data Access Layer. I think this situation does not conform to classic Layered Architecture - you should not call DAL directly from Application Layer.

So your code can be rewritten in another manner:

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
public IActionResult DoSomethingWithArgumentEntity(int id)
{
    this.DomainService.DoDomething(id);
    ...
}
```

In `DomainService` implementation you can read from repo whatever it needs for this specific operation. This avoids your troubles in Application Layer. In Business Layer you will have more freedom to implement reading: with serveral repository methods reads half-full entity, or with EnsureXXX methods, or something else. Knowledge about what you need to read for operation will be placed into operation's code and you don't need this knowledge in app-layer any more.

Every time situation like this emerged it is a strong signal about your entity is not preperly designed. As krzys said the entity has not cohesive parts. In other words if you often need parts of an entity separately you should split this entity.

Comment: I think I should clarify: repository here is an abstraction, it is of type IRepository and injected via DI. Repository interface is a part of business logic while repository implementation is a part of DAL. So DAL is not called from Application Layer. Problem 1: passing identifiers instead of entities to business layer is often considered to be a bad practice. Problem 2: what if you need to call DoSomething and DoSomethingElse in the same controller? In that case both methods will load entity so you will have two sql queries instead of one.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but logically repository interface is abstraction of persistance, so is logically belongs to DAL. Consider another problem: when you will write unit tests for app code you will stub not only domain services but repositories too. About problem 1: maybe, my experience is different. Problem 2: it is problem of infrastrcture, not problem of domain. Infrastructure (DAL) can implement some caching for such cases when multiple loads became a tangible problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question :)

I would argue that "related data" in itself is not a strict EF concept. Related data is a valid concept with NHibernate, with Dapper, or even if you use files for storage.

I agree with the other points mostly, though. So here's what I usually do: I have one repository method, in your case `GetById`, which has two parameters: the id and a `params Expression<Func<T,object>>[]`. And then, *inside* the repository I do the includes. This way you don't have any dependency on EF in your business logic (the expressions can be parsed manually for another type of data storage framework if necessary), and each BLL method can decide for themselves what related data they actually need.

```
public async Task<ArgumentEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id, params Expression<Func<ArgumentEntity,object>>[] includes)
{
    var baseQuery = ctx.ArgumentEntities; // ctx is a reference to your context
    foreach (var inlcude in inlcudes)
    {
       baseQuery = baseQuery.Include(include);
    }
    return await baseQuery.SingleAsync(a=>a.Id==id); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. Does it mean that you pass identifier to BLL methods and each BLL method call repository to load entity with required related data?

Comment: Basically yes. "Passing the id" can mean a lot of things  though: sometimes it means that BLL methods have an actual parameter, sometimes it means that BLL methods access the id through some kind of injected service. But at the end of the day, each BLL method is made somehow aware of the id and then they decide themselves which properties they need loaded and pass the expressions accordingly to the repository methods.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking in context of DDD, It seems that you had missed some modeling aspects in your project that led you to this issue. The Entity you wrote about looked not to be highly cohesive. If different related data is needed for different processes (service methods) it seems like you didn't find proper Aggregates yet. Consider splitting your Entity into several Aggregates with high cohesion. Then all processes correlated with particular Aggregate will need all or most of all data that this Aggregate contains.

So I don't know the answer for your question, but if you can afford to make few steps back and refactor your model, I believe you will not encounter such problems.

Comment: Well, it's not the answer but it's close to. Splitting aggregate will produce another problem - with the links between aggregates. But I just found an acceptable solution in [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919687/aggregate-root-references-other-aggregate-roots)