# Retrieve entity reference other aggregate by ids

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

One aggregate has to reference other aggregate by ids, for instance: order stores userId. So if I need the user entity to do something in the order aggregate I should pass it like this: order.doSomthing(user). But where should I retrieve the user in the application service or domain service?

Comment: This is way too context-dependent to throw a general answer at. The mention of a domain service and manipulating an aggregate from another aggregate also suggest design issues. You should be more specific about what the `Order` is trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't.**

An Aggregate operates/depends only on the data that it owns. This applies to write but also to read.

If an Aggregate, for example `User` needs some data from another Aggregate, for example  `Order`, then the Application service (or most probable a Saga/Process manager) gets the data from the `Order` and it passes it to the `User`:

```
user.doSomething(order.some, order.info)
```

Comment: so you mean that in the user application service I will have the orderRepository to get order? for example:
UserApplicationService {
  method() {
     orderId = user.orderId();
     order = orderRepository->findById(orderId);
     user.doSomething(order)
  }
}

Comment: @AgustinCastro no. The User does not own the Order. You will have something like: `user.doSomething(order.some, order.info)`

Comment: I see, but how can retrieve the order? and in the follow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919687/aggregate-root-references-other-aggregate-roots/4922100

there is a guy (David Masters) that says: "Then, if there is domain logic that involves both aggregates this can be extracted to a domain service and look something like this:"  he retrieve both aggregates from different repositories and do agg1.DoSomething(agg2);

Comment: @AgustinCastro you simply load both the Aggregates from the Repository. Regarding that link: I disagree; that would create a non-necesary coupling between the 2 Aggregates.

Comment: Therefore I should do something like that:
UserApplicationService { method() { orderId = user.orderId(); order = orderRepository->findById(orderId); user.doSomething(order.some, order.info) } }
right?

Comment: @AgustinCastro yes.